# web scraping accented and other special characters in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I made a script to parse spanish dict for the verb conjugations but always get the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xed' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when I try to print the characters with accents. When looking at the other similar questions, I realized that I need to encode and decode the accented characters, but don't know how to do this with my code. 
Here is my code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url  = "http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/hacer"

response = get(url)
#print(response.text[:500])

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

container = soup.find_all("a", class_ = "vtable-word-text")

for n in range(0,30,1):
    try:
        print(container[n].text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("accented character")
```

I have also added a try and except to tell me which ones are accented characters. Could anyone help me with my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine with Python 3.7, what version of Python are you using? https://bpaste.net/show/94d71b4de8b6

Comment: I am using the atom scripting package, let me try getting python 3.7

Comment: @G_M what ide are you using? On idle it says that the requests module is not found

Comment: PyCharm Professional with IPython for my Python console but I have `requests` and `bs4` installed in this virtual environment already.

Comment: @G_M Thank you I will try that.

Comment: The IDE shouldn't be the problem, it just seems like you either don't have `requests` and `bs4` installed or IDLE is using a different Python interpreter than the one you would have installed those two on.